# Modal verbs confusion

Tags: modal-verbs

What should I use, in this certain situation?

> It will be better if they create private charity, *so everyone .... able to join.*

What do the dots have to be?.

I was going to put, "can be". however, as they haven't created the event yet, it won't be correct right?

Or "could be", but that's neither in the past nor possibility.

What is the correct answer for the dots? Please provide the detailed information, thank you.

Comment: Can be. You already proposed definite possibility for charity.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, It sounds like stating a fact, but the event doesn't occur as it is a notion, which means no one can really be able to join, it may have rules, could you please explain it to me? Thanks before

Comment: Whether it occurred or not, if there is a definite possibility that it can happen and not hypothetical, then it must use "can be". You eliminated the chance of its being intangible by using the modal verb will, which suggests its possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> It will be better if they create private charity, so everyone **will
>   be** able to join.

Can be able is present, will be able is future and fits better in the sentence.

I read this here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/will-be-able-to-vs-can